# convert from dfa to regex

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I was asked to form this automata to a regular expresssion :

[image]

so far im stuck at this stage :

[image]

can somepne help me please ?

Comment: I recommend http://www.jflap.org - it very useful for converting between regexes/automata . Also you could ask this at https://cs.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I believe that I've got an answer, but I'm reluctant to post it, for these reasons: (1) I have no process: I just played with it in my mind for a few minutes.  (2) I haven't tested it.  (3) It's almost 40 characters long.  It can probably be simplified, but I'm having trouble doing that.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) … But what you have doesn't look right. (4) ```1*1+1*1``` doesn't make any sense.  Think about what strings match that (any string of one or more `1`s? or two or more?) and think about how you would represent that.  (5) It looks like your DFA matches only strings ending with `e` ($\epsilon$?).  Clearly the DFA you were given matches strings ending with `0` or `1`.  Am I misunderstanding what you mean by "f"?